# How to get the attribute data of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, raphael

I am using a chart from Raphael.js and I really have a very little experience with javascript and JQuery that's why I would like to ask you guys, so I'll go straight to the point.

I have some problems regarding the fill data. I simply wanted to get all the fill data (in this example there are two text tags so I wanted to get two `fill="#ff0000"` and `fill="#00e0ff"`

```
<text style="font: 20px "Arial"; opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle;" x="555.0919781452639" y="222.43750078648324" text-anchor="middle" font="10px "Arial"" stroke="none" fill="#ff0000" opacity="1" font-size="20px">
   <tspan dy="7.000000786483241">Ruby</tspan>
</text>

<text style="font: 20px "Arial"; opacity: 1; text-anchor: middle;" x="604.746975531892" y="434.94193863997384" text-anchor="middle" font="10px "Arial"" stroke="none" fill="#00e0ff" opacity="0" font-size="20px">
   <tspan dy="7.000532389973841">PHP</tspan>
</text>
```

anyway i created a jsfiddle account for it i really still don't have an idea can you guys help me out? http://jsfiddle.net/psyreaper3/rXXem/9/

Comment: Do you build those SVG elements with RaphaelJS or with a framework on top of RaphaelJS or get it flatten as xml from another content source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try put this code in your callback function :

```
$('text').each(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('fill'));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat ugly looking but functional solution would be:

`$($('text')[0]).attr('fill');` (Which would give you the first text's fill attribute) and
`$($('text')[1]).attr('fill');` (Which would give you the second).

You would ideally use an id's on these elements to make it easy for you to get a particular text elements attribute.

`<text id="first" fill="blah"></text>` and then you can do `$('#first').attr('fill');`

Answer (score 0):

You can get fill property this way.

```
$('text').each(function(){
   alert($(this).prop('fill'));
})
```

Answer (score 0):

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rXXem/11/)

You can get fill attribute by:

```
$(this).attr('fill');
```

and can update it by using:

```
$(this).attr('fill','#ffee00');
```